# total amount is messed up when calculated all the price C++

Tags: c++

so i have try to make something using c++ all the code i make run smoothly without an error but the problem is, the "payment" is not correct it just way to much from the "payment" i tried changing it from "int" into long doesnt work either double and float. here is the code and the output.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
main()
{
  char brand[6][20]={"DA","da","TO","to","HO","ho"},car[6],*info[6];
  int  j,a,amount[6],tax[6],rent[6],total[6],final[6];
  long final_total[20];
  int price[15]={200000,300000,400000,500000,600000,250000,450000,550000,350000,375000,425000,555000};

cout<<"\t\t\t***rental mobil sederhana***"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t**Jalan tebet raya no.15**"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t============================"<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<"\tinformasi merk dan mobil yang tersedia"<<endl;
cout<<"DAIHATSU [DA] : 1. Ayla    3. Luxio  "<<endl;
cout<<"                2. Sigra   4. Terios "<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"TOYOTA   [TO] : 1. Innova  3. Avanza "<<endl;
cout<<"                2. Yaris   4. Veloz  "<<endl;
cout<<"-------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"HONDA    [HO] : 1. Mobilio 3. Civic  "<<endl;
cout<<"              : 2. Jazz    4. Brio   "<<endl;
cout<<"amount :"; cin>>j;
amount[j]=0;
if(j<=0)
{
 cout<<"banyak mobil tidak bisa kosong";
}
else
{
 for(a=1;a<=j; a++)
 {
  cout<<"car number -"<<a<<endl;
  cout<<"enter the car brand :"; cin>>brand[a];
  cout<<"enter the car code  :" ; cin>>car[a];
  cout<<"how long            :"; cin>>rent[a];
if(brand[a]=="DA" || brand[a]=="da")
{
 if(car[a]==1)
 {
 info[a]= "Ayla";
 price[a]=200000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==2)
 {
 info[a]= "Sigra";
 price[a]=300000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==3)
 {
 info[a]= "Luxio";
 price[a]=400000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==4)
 {
 info[a]= "Terios";
 price[a]=500000;
 }
}
else if(brand[a]=="TO" || brand[a]=="to")
{
 if(car[a]==1)
 {
 info[a]= "Innova";
 price[a]=600000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==2)
 {
 info[a]= "Yaris";
 price[a]=250000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==3)
 {
 info[a]= "Avanza";
 price[a]=450000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==4)
 {
 info[a]= "Veloz";
 price[a]=550000;
 }
}
else if(brand[a]=="HO" || brand[a]=="ho")
{
 if(car[a]==1)
 {
 info[a]= "Mobilio";
 price[a]=350000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==2)
 {
 info[a]= "Jazz";
 price[a]=375000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==3)
 {
 info[a]= "Civic";
 price[a]=425000;
 }
 else if(car[a]==4)
 {
 info[a]= "Brio";
 price[a]=555000;
 }
}
total[a]=rent[a]*price[a];
final_total[j]=final_total[j]+total[a]*price[a];
if(final_total[j]<=0)
{
 tax[j]=0;
 final[j]=0;
 }
 else
 {
  tax[j]=final_total[j]*0.25;
  final[j]=final_total[j]+tax[j];
  }
 }
}
cout<<"\t\t\tRental mobil sederhana"<<endl;
cout<<"========================================="<<endl;
cout<<"no.| car  | car   | price | Total"<<endl;
cout<<"   | brand| name  |       | price "<<endl;
cout<<"========================================="<<endl;
for(a=1;a<=j; a++)
{
 cout<<" "<<a<<"|"<<brand[a]<<"  |";
 cout<<"      |"<<price[a]<<"  | Rp."<<total[a]<<endl;
}
cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
cout<<"payment       :Rp. "<<final_total[j]<<endl;
cout<<"tax 25%          :Rp. "<<tax[j]<<endl;
cout<<"total payment        :Rp. "<<final[j]<<endl;
getch();
}
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijCPH.png)

the messed up number is in the end at "payment". my tax and final payment get affected too by the messed up number. Thanks! and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems here.

1. arrays begin at 0: not at 1.  The prices have been initialized to 20000, 30000, 40000 etc.  price[1] is 30000: not 20000.  Not sure why you are initializing price because you are overwriting all the prices in the if statements below.
2. final_total needs to be initialized before it is used: hence the messed up number. This needs to be done before your first cout.
3. total[a] = rent[a] * price[a] - that makes sense but you are starting at 1.  If you print out all the elements in total, the first value is blank, second element has your calculated total.  This is because arrays begin at 0.
4. final_total[j] = final_total[j] + total[a] * price[a] - why multiply by the price again?

Learn how to use the debugger: it will save you a lot of time.

Semoga berhasil

Comment: where should i change the problem number "1" you mention? and problem number "2" im already initiate it on the code,maybe im doing it wrong? and cara enter kebawah disini gimana?? mencet enter malah ke save hehehe. thank you very much!